# cross dll debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003

Im using vs 2003. When I try to debug some program that uses several dll files i can debug
(put breakpoint - without question mark) only on the cpp files of the project that creates
the dll and was the last one that i compiled . breakpoints located on others dlls (that are part of the program and located in the same solution) are marked with question mark and the debugger doesnt reach them at all.

how can i solve it ??
thanks,
liran

Answer (score 1):

You must build these dll's as debug and make sure they have the correct symbols in them?  just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can load up the symbols from other assemblies by [specifying the symbols path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx) to them in Visual Studio. I'm not sure if the feature is in VS2003 or not, however.